# How to parse the values in excel file and store it in database using django

Tags: django, excel, django-models, django-forms, xlrd

1.I am working in a project,were i am storing student name and phone number in a spreadsheet(.xls).

2.I am using django framework,in my app which have a button namely import from spreadsheet.So if i press this button i should able to upload a .xls file,and by pressing the save button the details namely name and phone number should be saved in database using parsing.

So how to achieve this.

My models.py is

```
class Contactlist
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, null=True)
    cname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pnumber = models.IntegerField()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) and write a method in your class that receives an Excel spreadsheet as input and imports the data. [This site](http://blog.nerdstogeeks.com/2011/05/reading-excel-data-using-python.html) gives an example of how to use it in general, [here is an example of using it in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15503966/868044) to accomplish this task.

You could also try the existing [django-excel-import module](https://github.com/foreveryh/django-excel-import).

Comment: https://github.com/foreveryh/django-excel-import that link is not working.So were should i write the parseing code ,in views.py or in forms.py

Comment: I would write it as a method in the model itself so all the form has to do is pass the Excel spreadsheet to the method and receive the output