# Importing data into django from CSV via admin interface

Tags: django, csv, django-admin

I'm developing a django application that will need regular updates of its database from a number of CSV files. These will need to be uploaded via the web interface. Are there any libraries/modules that I should look at to make this easier?

Victor

Comment: Looks like this will do what I need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974620/import-csv-data-into-database-in-django-admin

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [Django import_export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

Answer (score -1):

Making what easier? Your question is rather vague, but from what I understand you would need something to scedule the job at regular intervals. This could be done in lots of ways, but usually by a python script and a cronjob or a celery task.

Comment: I'm referring to the uploading and parsing of the file. The uploading of the file will be done manually; I'm not interested in scheduling that.

Comment: You could just use python's csv module and django's serializers, I was referring to sceduling because parsing large files on model save seems wrong

Comment: Can django deserialize from a CSV? Why is parsing large files on model save wrong? (btw by regularly I meant a few times a year)

Comment: If you intend to parse a large upload with the save method of a django model(form), you will need to deal with a user that's just watching for a response to return (which might take a while) also you would have to handle errors when parsing fails. It seems likely to create a task for things like this and email a report, but tbh that's just my personal opinion :-)