# Django user csv import

Tags: python, django, django-forms

For my Django app I have a request page that allows users to make multiple requests(like an order form) in a single submission. If the user has many requests I don't want them to fill about the forms one by one.

I currently have django-import-export installed for the admin. Is there a way to allow the user to import a csv file to the database? If not, what would be a good solution to make the form process more user friendly?

Comment: `django-import-export` allows importing CSV, doesn't it?

Comment: It does, but I only got it working for the admin. I am unsure of how to allow users to import a csv.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood you. Did you try [`import_data`](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/import_workflow.html#import-data-method-workflow) method?

Comment: Also, [_how to import csv data into django models_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459979/how-to-import-csv-data-into-django-models) and [_Import csv data into database in Django Admin_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974620/import-csv-data-into-database-in-django-admin) questions might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the links. Have you done csv imports yourself? Care to explain?

Comment: I have done it for admins only.